# To view pdf file in web view

Tags: android, pdf, webview

Here is my question:- I have many pdf files in my application in files folder.I want to display them on web view when user clicks on its hyperlink from another web view.

That is I have one web view which dynamically generates a html page from html template stored in asset folder.In that there we have one hyperlink of pdf file corresponding to data displayed.When user clicks on hyperlink I want to display it in web view.Can it be possible?

Please reply.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way for you is using Google Docs.
You can implement in your application [Pdf-viewer](https://drive.googleblog.com/2009/09/view-online-files-using-google-docs.html) from Google Docs.

Just put in your html page following code:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://YOUR-URL&embedded=true" width="500" height="250"></iframe>
```

You can catch user click and redirect user to special page with Google Docs Pdf-viewer

Comment: Thank you for answer but doesn't match my criteria.